# If there is a given relation(A,B,C,D) and some dependencies on this relation and now we find candidate keys on the relation with attributes(B,C,D)

Tags: database

In dbms, If there is a given relation with attributes(A,B,C,D) and some dependencies are given on this relation and now we find candidate keys on the relation with attributes(B,C,D)?What should be the approach to find the candidate keys on the relation?

Comment: I have read the question at least 5 times but I can not understand it. Which are "some dependencies"? Are you talking about two different candidate keys? On which you have found, and another which you have not? And are you then talking about two different relations or the same one? I don't understand.

Comment: let dependencies can be like that A->B, A->C, B->A and there is no two different relation both are the same only difference in the attribute.

Comment: @Ronnis is it clear now?